ASP.NET Core 6 MVC call dependency injection in constructor from html page
I have a link in html file that calls method in controller:
<a asp-action="Detail" asp-route-modelId="@item.Id">Detail</a>

This is the method being called:
[HttpGet]
public virtual IActionResult Detail(Guid modelId, MyModel modell)
{
    // TODO
}

When this method is called (and it creates an instance of class MyModel), it uses the default empty constructor instead of the constructor with context passed by dependency injection.
Normally when I call to get my class from context (context.MyModel.ToList();), it uses the correct constructor.
    public MyModel (ModelContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }

    public MyModel ()
    {
        this.Context = null;
    }

So my question is - what am I doing wrong? And how can I "force" to use controller with context?
Thank you
I have tried googling and watch some Youtube videos about it, but with no luck.

your detail method will not be hit... it's trying to take class objects as passed in arguments.  This won't happen via GET.   Usually controller-type classes extend controller or something similar that already has a default, no argument, constructor.  Your services will usually be configured to call these endpoints with a DB context so will hit your constructor that takes the context as an argument.
